# Nothing happens when using Cypher-shell for executing scripts

Tags: neo4j, cypher-shell

I'm trying to execute a series of Cypher queries using Cypher shell according to [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/). I have created a file called "cypher.ex1" and placed it into import and bin folder. Here is its content:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n;

MATCH (batman:Person {name: 'Bruce Wayne'}) RETURN batman;
```

I'm trying to execute it using:

```
$neo4j-home> cat cypher.ex1 | bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 123456 --format plain
```

but when I run this, nothing happens and after waiting for a long time with no output, I need to press "CTRL + C" to terminate the command. Here is an screenshot of the problem:

[image]

In fact, cypher-shell works fine for one line commands, but not for scripts. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute this command line:

```
cat cypher.ex1 | bin/cypher.shell -u neo4j - 123456
```

from *within* the `cypher.shell` environment. That will not work, since `cypher.shell` only supports Cypher statements and a limited set of commands (use the `:help` command to see what is available).

The reason nothing happened for you (not even an error) is because `cypher.shell` did not see a colon (':') at the start of your command line, so it assumed that you were entering a Cypher statement and was waiting (forever) for the ending semicolon (';') before parsing it.

If you want to execute that exact command line, you have to execute it *outside* of `cypher-shell` (when it is not running).

However, if you really do want to perform the equivalent action from *within* the `cypher.shell` environment, you can use its `:source` command. For example:

```
:source cypher.ex1
```

The default location for the source file is the "current working directory", which is the directory you were in when you launched `cypher.shell`. If the file is elsewhere, you can specify the relative path of the file from the current working directory as the `:source` argument.

Comment: After executing ":source cypher.ex1", this came up: Cannot find file: 'cypher.ex1'
Where should I put the "cypher.ex1"?

Comment: By default, the "current working directory", which is the directory you were in when you launched `cypher.shell`. If the file is not there, the `:source` argument can be a relative path from that directory. I have added this info to my answer.